# ASP.NET Core MVC parameterized validation, conditional validation or validation of a property based on its parent class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two model properties for my form, Max and Min that are responsible for any Max or Min value within my form, which I validate to make sure they are decimals and are present, also I validate the range

```
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^\\d+(.\\d+){0,1}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Value")]
    [MaxMinRange("Allowed range (0-100)")]
    public string Minimum { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^\\d+(.\\d+){0,1}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Value")]
    [MaxMinRange("Allowed range (0-100)")]
    public string Maximum { get; set; }
```

Here is my custom validator for the range

```
public class MaxMinRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private String ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public MaxMinRangeAttribute(String errormessage)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = errormessage;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            double maxmin;
            bool isDouble = Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out maxmin);

            if (isDouble && Convert.ToDouble(value.ToString()) > 100)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

However, Max and Min model properties in my View/cshtml page come representing different parent classes, such as percentages of chemical composition or millimeters

(chemical composition percentage)

```
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.ChemicalComposition[20].Value.Minimum" />
        <span asp-validation-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.ChemicalComposition[20].Value.Minimum" class="alert-danger"></span>
   </td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.ChemicalComposition[21].Value.Minimum" />
     <span asp-validation-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.ChemicalComposition[21].Value.Minimum" class="alert-danger"></span>
  </td>
```

Millimeters

```
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.ProductDimensions[0].Value.Minimum" />
    <span asp-validation-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.ProductDimensions[0].Value.Minimum" class="alert-danger"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.ProductDimensions[1].Value.Minimum" />
     <span asp-validation-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.ProductDimensions[1].Value.Minimum" class="alert-danger"></span>
  </td>
```

The percentages obviously shouldn't be bigger than 100; however, millimeters can be

My question is how can I validate same model properties differently based on a parent class, extra properties, or maybe some additional parameters?

How can I validate Max/Min for percentages not being greater than 100 but disregard this validation for Max/Min millimeters?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: The `ValidationContext` is the model itself (it knows nothing about any parent model) so you cannot (unless your model contains a property indicating the 'maximum' value and you use conditional validation). But why is you property `string` when its clearly numeric (it should be `decimal` or `double` etc). And why are you using a custom `ValidationAttribute` when the in-built `[Range]` does that (and gives you client side validation as well)

Comment: The code is NOT perfect, that is what I have

For some reason the built in range validator didn't work for me

Is there a way to supply the model property with additional parameter to apply the validation conditionally?

Comment: Your model (the one with `Minimum` and `Maximum`) would need to include a (say) `public decimal MaximumLimit { get; set; }` property and you set that in the GET method based on the parent, then include a hidden input for it in the view so that its posted back, and you can then check your `Maximum` against then `MaximumLimit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up updating our model (Couldn't avoid it). We had create an extra property specifically for the percentage

```
public class MaxMin
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^\\d+(.\\d+){0,1}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Value")]
    public string Minimum { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^\\d+(.\\d+){0,1}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Value")]
    public string Maximum { get; set; }
}

public class MaxMinPercentage
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^\\d+(.\\d+){0,1}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Value")]
    [MaxMinRange("Allowed range (0-100)")]
    public string Minimum { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^\\d+(.\\d+){0,1}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Value")]
    [MaxMinRange("Allowed range (0-100)")]
    public string Maximum { get; set; }
}
```